# Am I able to define something within a class with variables that can be accessed

Tags: python

I am very new to programming and im not sure if i worded the question correctly.

I am trying to make a program that simulates basic plant growth during different "seasons" and during various "weather" events as well the type of "soil" they are in.

For example:
if season = summer, then growth rate = 1x and there is a .9 chance of sunny weather and .1 chance of rainy weather.

If i make a class called Summer(), is it possible to define the growth rate and weather events for this particular season and access them later on?

The code i currently have is this:

```
class Season():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.getSeason = name
    
    def getGrowthRate(self):
        if self.getSeason == "Summer":
            return 1
        #then so forth for the rest of them

    def getWeatherEvent(self):
        if self.getSeason == "Summer":
            # i dont know how to do this part, but for example, sunny = 0.9, rainy = 0.1 chance
```

is it posible to define the seasons (and maybe weather events) as seperate entities and access the values that i need from inside them?

This probably isnt very clear, but any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you may want to read about class inheritance, it seems to me that what you want is separate classes for each season that inherit the methods from the Season class and contain the attributes as class variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this approach, don't need inheritance, if you want them to change the season every time you call it you can default it to None and put @property decorating his method.

```
import random

class Season:
    seasons_data = {'summer':{'sunny':0.9, 'rain':0.1, 'snow':0},
                    'winter':{'sunny':0.1, 'rain':0.6, 'snow':0.2}}
    growth_rate = {'summer':1,'winter':0.4}
    
    seasons = list(seasons_data.keys())
    def __init__(self, season=None):
        self.season = season  # random.choices(seasons)
        self.weather = self.get_weather()
        self.growth = self.growth_rate[self.season]
        
    def get_weather(self):
        current_season_data = self.seasons_data[self.season]
        return random.choices(list(current_season_data.keys()), current_season_data.values())[0]
    
summer_season = Season('summer') #instance of summer
print(summer_season.weather) # fixed
print(summer_season.growth) # fixed growth of summer
print(summer_season.get_weather()) # randomize weather of summer
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for this reply. This code is very insightful with my studies, however, when i run it, i get a type error when the program runs that last line of code, " dict is not callable", any idea what this means and how to fix it?

Comment: @patrickc for me it works ok, but I edited it so you can see a usage example.  Do you have python 3.6 or newer? If you use jupyter remember to restart the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the examples, I have python 3.10.2. I have just restarted the system in case and for whatever reason it works as it should. This has heleped immensely, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

For me natural way would be to have class `Season` and instances of said class: summer, fall, winter, spring. I propose following implementation

```
import random
class Season:
    conditions = ("sunny", "rainy")
    def __init__(self, name, weights):
        self.name = name
        self.weights = weights
    def get_weather(self):
        return random.choices(self.conditions, self.weights)[0]
summer = Season("summer",[0.9,0.1])
fall = Season("fall",[0.5,0.5])
winter = Season("winter",[0.1,0.9])
spring = Season("spring",[0.5,0.5])
print(summer.get_weather()) # rainy
print(summer.get_weather()) # sunny
print(summer.get_weather()) # sunny
```

Output might differ as it is non-deterministic. `conditions` is *class attribute* meaning it is shared by all instances, name and weights are *instances attributes*. I use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) as it allows weights as 2nd argument, it return list (in this case with 1 element) so we need to get that element by using `[0]`.